# only delete relation row when all rows not exist

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I'm using foreign key tried to check if when user delete table `gallery` `gallery_id` `0` , and there's no row `gallery_id = 0` exist then delete table `article_gallery`.

I know it can be use php check if no row exist then delete, but wondering is there any other way can
do it more smart?
I tried foreign key, but it should be not work, it delete row in table `article_gallery` if delete any `gallery_id = 0` in table `gallery` even it still has another row `gallery_id = 0`.

```
CONSTRAINT `article_gallery_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`gallery_id`) REFERENCES `gallery` (`gallery_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

**Table: article_gallery**

```
id | article_id | gallery_id  
---------------------------------------------------------
0    0            0  
1    1            0  
2    2            1
```

**Table: gallery**

```
id | gallery_id  
---------------------------------------------------------------------
0    0  
1    0  
2    0  
3    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER delete_gallery AFTER DELETE ON gallery
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        DELETE FROM article_gallery AS a
        WHERE a.gallery_id = OLD.gallery_id
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                          FROM gallery AS g
                          WHERE g.gallery_id = OLD.gallery_id);
    END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! if compare this or do it in php, which one you will be recommend

Comment: If you do it in PHP, you have to do it in every script that deletes rows from the table. If you do it in a trigger, you just have to do it in once place.

Comment: I google it seems if consider performance should be put logic in php much better?

Comment: Do you delete rows very frequently? If not, then performance probably isn't critical.